# How to write exponential function for curve that pass 4 or more points

Tags: functions, roots, exponentiation, curves

Given 3 points, we could write exponential function for a curve that would pass those points in $y = ax^n + b$ form

So I wonder that, could we write a function in exponential form that would pass 4 points, which is not quadratic or cubic bezier

Or are there any formula that could construct a function for curve to pass any given points?

Edit : Sorry I was misunderstand the word exponential function. What I really mean is rational exponent function

I don't know what it called but it not polynomial. Something like $y = ax^{1.5} + b$ but can pass any 4 or more points

Comment: $y=ax^n+b$ isn't exponential, it's a polynomial. For your question, are you asking for an exponential curve ($y = ab^x+c$) or a specific kind of polynomial? If the latter, what form are you wanting the polynomial to take? Given $n$ points, one can always find a polynomial of degree $n-1$ passing through all of the points.

Comment: @Florence: provided $n$ is an integer, which isn't true for three arbitrary points. This is more a power law, though shifted by the term $b$.

Comment: You are not telling us enough of the motivation behind "an exponential form but not a Bezier".

Comment: @florence Sorry but I really put n there as any real number not just integer. x and y is the variable of a point. I work by finding b n and then a with 3 equation from 3 points

Comment: @YvesDaoust Nothing in particular. I just want to know that are there anyway to extend exponential function into 4 points. But bezier is polynomial

Comment: @YvesDaoust If you ask why not bezier. It because I already know how to do with bezier so I want to know other way then I can compare it, and exponential is interesting for me

Comment: In the context of your question "exponential" is both wrong and too vague.

Answer (score 2):

As the equation $y=ax^n+b$ has three independent parameters, you can constrain it to pass through three given points, but not more.

If you add more terms or terms with more coefficients, you can increase the flexibility. For example, the linear combination of four independent functions.

Possibilities are infinite.

Comment: That's what I try to find, I want to know which way and how I could add more terms in a way that it will let me find a function to pass 4 or more point. As of exponential function, if I have 3 points I could find exponent and coefficient easily. So how to put more terms to work out that?

Comment: @Thaina: there are too many possibilities. You must have some understanding of the underlying physical/behavioral model to make a sound choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try taking a look at [Lagrange polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Examples).

In general, if you have $n$ points, there exists a polynomial of degree at most $n$ that goes through those points. In the example linked above, notice that $f(2) = 4$. When we plug in $2$ into the Lagrange polynomial, notice that the first term and the last term equals zero (since $x-2 = 2-2 = 0$ in the numerator) and in the middle term, we get 
$$4\cdot \frac{x-1}{2-x} \cdot \frac{x-3}{2-3} = 4 \cdot \frac{2-1}{2-1} \cdot \frac{2-3}{2-3} = 4(1)(1) = 4,$$
and so we get $f(2) = 0+4+0 = 4$.

Similarly, if we plug in the $x$ in the first point, you get $1$ in the first term and the other terms end up being zero. The same kind of thing happens with the third point.

So you can do the same kind of thing with 4 points and get up to a 4th degree polynomial which could be written as a Lagrange polynomial with 4 terms.

EDIT:

Suppose that we only want an exponential function. In other words, some sequence of transformations (translations, reflections, stretches/dilations) of the function $e^x$. Then such a function would look like $f(x) = a\cdot e^{b(x-c)}+d$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ where $a$ and $b$ are nonzero.

But notice,
$$f(x) = a\cdot e^{b(x-c)}+d = (a \cdot e^{-bc})e^{bx}+d = ke^{bx}+d,$$

where $k = a \cdot e^{-bc}$.

This means that every exponential function $f$ can be written as,
$$f(x) = ae^{bx}+c,$$
where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ where $a$ and $b$ are nonzero.

Now suppose that you have four points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3), (x_4, y_4)$ and you want to find the values of $a,b,c$ you need to fit your four points to an exponential function. Then for each $(x_i, y_i)$ you have the equation,

$$y_i = f(x_i) = ae^{bx_i}+c.$$

Notice you have four equations (one for each point) and three variables you need to solve for ($a, b, c$) so in most cases, this system will have no solutions, hence no exponential function will exist that will fit your four points.

Comment: Thanks for that but I want exponential one

Comment: What do you mean by exponential exactly? In your question, $y(x) = ax^n+b$ is not an exponential function. What is the general form you are looking for? Do you mean some sequence of basic transformations (translations, stretches, reflections) of the function $f(x) = e^x$?

Comment: Just edited my answer. Assuming you agree with my definition of exponential function, in general there is no exponential function that will fit four points.

Answer (score 1):

QUESTION : could we write a function in exponential form that would pass 4 points, which is not quadratic or cubic Bezier ?

ANSWER : Yes, for example 
$$y=a(x-\mu)^\nu+b$$
Determine the parameters $a\:,\:b\:,\:\nu\:,\:\mu$ according to the coordinates of the four points with numerical calculus.

Comment: Would you pleased to explain some example to determine parameter?

Comment: You have four given points $(x_1\:,\:y_1)$ , $(x_2\:,\:y_2)$ , $(x_3\:,\:y_3)$ , $(x_4\:,\:y_4)$ , so, a system of four equations ; $$\begin{cases} y_1=a(x_1-\mu)^\nu+b \\y_2=a(x_2-\mu)^\nu+b \\y_3=a(x_3-\mu)^\nu+b \\y_4=a(x_4-\mu)^\nu+b \end{cases}$$ You have to solve it for $a$ , $b$ , $\nu$ , $\mu$. Since the equations are not linear, you have to use some numerical method of solving, generally involving initial guess and iterative process ( generalized Newton-Raphson or others). Search on the web for more information.

Comment: If you have four points but only three parameters : $y=ax^\nu+b$, the fitted curve generally cannot pass exactly the four points. It is only possible to optimise the three parameters so that the curve pass close to the four points. This is a so called "regression" problem. Search on the web with key words "regression" and "fitting".

Comment: I'm not limit to 3 parameters. I just want to know the best and easiest way to add the additional parameter. And I would like it to be rational exponent instead of polymomial

Comment: I'm not limit to 3 parameters. I just want to know the best and easiest way to add the additional parameter. And I would like it to be rational exponent instead of polymomial

Comment: The easiest way should be to NOT use a function of exponential kind. In so far you want an exponential function, the calculus will require numerical non-linear solving methods which are not simple. To be simpler, follow the advices given in the other answers that you got.